# Use DataTemplate from App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

In my App.xaml I have defined a `DataTemplate` for my DataType Entry. In this `DataTemplate` I'm creating a `Grid` with several rows and columns.

The xaml of my `DataTemplate` looks like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplate" DataType="entity:Entry" x:Name="EntryTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="hCBase:HControlBase" x:Key="TopRowMargin">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,50,2"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <hC:HComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="Entry-Type:" Style="{StaticResource TopRowMargin}" SelectedIndex="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EntryTypesDataProvider}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding EntryType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

> The Template is not finished yet.

Now I want to use this `DataTemplate` in a Window, where I have an Entry-Object in the ViewModel. But at the moment I have no glue how to use this.

What do I have to do to display the Entry-Object from my ViewModel in my View using my DataTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I create `ContentControl`, for example in MainWindow with `ContentTemplate` like this:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplate}"> 

    <entity:Entry /> <!-- Your ViewModel here -->
</ContentControl>
```